# What is the best way to encapsulate inherited fields in Unity 2D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, inheritance, private, encapsulation

I'm currently designing a Unity game, and I want to ensure I'm implementing proper encapsulation. However, I'm stuck on this problem:

Suppose I have a class `Item` with the field: `private string itemName`. I also have a class `Strawberry` that is a subclass of `Item`. I want to write a method in class `Strawberry` that returns its itemName.

These scripts are MonoBehaviour, so they cannot contain constructors that would solve the problem above using `base` in its constructor.

What strategy should I use to set the `Strawberry` class' name?

Thanks!

Comment: [`protected`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/protected) ...

Answer (score 1):

You need to make your `itemName` string protected. That means it can be accessed by child classes.

Item base class:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Item : MonoBehaviour
{
    protected string itemName = "itemBase";
}
```

Strawberry class:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Strawberry : Item
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log($"my mane is: {GetItemName()}"); 
    }

    string GetItemName() => this.itemName;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But where would I actually declare that Strawberry's itemName should be "Strawberry"?

Comment: where it makes more sense is in the strawberry class itself, doest it¿?

Comment: and why not simply `Debug.Log($"my name is: {itemName}");` ;)